# NS3 installation failed on ubuntu 18

Tags: virtualbox, simulation, ubuntu-18.04, ns-3

Can someone share how to solve this problem to install ns3? i am trying to configure it by following  but get these errors:

https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Installation

```
"  >> Download ns-3.26 - OK
root@maryyam-VirtualBox:/home/maryyam# bake.py build
>> Building castxml - OK
>> Building netanim-3.107 - Problem
> Problem: Optional dependency, module "netanim-3.107" failed "
 This may reduce the  functionality of the final build. 
 However, bake will continue since "netanim-3.107" is not an essential           dependency.
 For more information call bake with -v or -vvv, for full verbose mode.

 ">> Building pygccxml - Problem
 > Problem: Optional dependency, module "pygccxml" failed
 This may reduce the  functionality of the final build. 
 However, bake will continue since "pygccxml" is not an essential dependency.
  For more information call bake with -v or -vvv, for full verbose mode.

  >> Building pybindgen-0.17.0.post57+nga6376f2 - Problem
  > Problem: Optional dependency, module "pybindgen-  0.17.0.post57+nga6376f2" failed
This may reduce the  functionality of the final build. 
However, bake will continue since "pybindgen-0.17.0.post57+nga6376f2" is not an essential dependency.
For more information call bake with -v or -vvv, for full verbose mode.
>> Building ns-3.26 -   
Problem
> Error:  Critical dependency, module "ns-3.26" failed 
For more information call Bake with --debug and/or -v, -vvv, for full verbose mode (bake --help)
```